# MySql - Get next date which satisfy a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called '`helper_leaves`' in which user have entered their leave dates for the next 2 months.

I would like to get **2 upcoming working dates** for a particular `user_id` which are **NOT** in the '`helper_leaves`' table and also should be **next to the current date.**

```
**id | user_id | leave_date** 

 1   |   1     | 2016-07-07 
 2   |   1     | 2016-07-09 
 3   |   1     | 2016-07-15 
 4   |   1     | 2016-08-03
```

I want write a  query to get next 2 working dates of `user_id = 1`, from now.
Please note, this table is having only the **leave dates**. But I want to get the next 2 **availability dates** .

For the sample data given, I expected to get **2016-07-14**  and **2016-07-16** as the next 2 working dates because today is **2016-07-13**

**Note: All the dates which are not in this table is considered as a working date.**

Please help!!!!

Comment: You want to get the leave date? I don't see a working date column? Or do you want to get where not in the table?

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here, given the sample data, what's your desired output?

Comment: Edited the question !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with below query?
In that, i have just generate next 60 dates and exclude leave_date from that with limit 2.

```
SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL a + b DAY dte
FROM
 (SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) d,
 (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 
    UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40) m
WHERE CURDATE() + INTERVAL a + b DAY  <  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) and dte not in ( select leave_date from helper_leaves where user_id = 1)
ORDER BY a + b limit  2
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use interval

For Ex:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(leave_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS workingDay;
```

Comment: Sorry, this will get the leave date only. I awnt to get the next availability date of that user.

Comment: no,this will add the +1 day to the leave_date actually!!

Comment: Yes , but that can be another leave day. I want to get the availability date always , that too next to the current date.

Comment: ok...for that add WHERE condition: "WHERE leave_date != workingDay AND user_id = X"

Comment: SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE(leave_date_start) , INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS workingDay 
FROM helper_leaves
WHERE leave_date != workingDay AND user_id = 1 .

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'workingDay' in 'where clause'

Comment: bro,it should work..may be date format issue!Sorry,I'm in hurry can't help you rigjht now.